# Should the [CultureInfo] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I was doing some searches for globalization in C# and one of the tags I saw that popped up in my search was [cultureinfo](/questions/tagged/cultureinfo). If I recall, one of the criteria for the usefulness of a tag was whether or not the tag could stand alone in a question.

The biggest issue I see with [cultureinfo](/questions/tagged/cultureinfo) is that the tag seems to almost exclusively reference the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` class in the .NET Framework. This sort of information is implicit for us users of C# but outside of C# it may not necessarily exist.

I did a quick scan of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cultureinfo) page for [cultureinfo](/questions/tagged/cultureinfo) and I didn't really see any questions that were *just* for the `CultureInfo`. Everything I saw is tagged with something else that refers to .NET in some shape or form.

So, should this tag be removed? It seems like deadweight and doesn't really convey any information on it's own.

Comment: Doesn't convey any information? You just said that it pretty much references `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`. Therefore, tagging something with [tag:cultureinfo] tells us that the question has something to do with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`. That's hardly deadweight.

Comment: C#, IronPython, F#, VB.NET, etc etc etc

Answer (score 3):

That would be an argument to remove all major class and lib tags.

jQuery can't function without javaScript, should we remove the tag?

So my answer is No.